# How do I create a lossless screencast using Fedora and Wayland?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, gnome, screencasts, wayland

**Environment:**

Fedora 34, 5.12.13-300.fc34.x86_64

FFMPEG 4.4-4.fc34

GNOME 40.1.0

**What I am trying to do:**

Create a lossless screencast file (video only, audio not required) that can be used as a source file for video editing.

**What have I tried**

- GNOME built-in screen recorder
  This does a great job recording, but the output file (.webm) has lossy compression
- ffmpeg
  I found this command:
  `ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -c:v qtrle output.mov`
  which did a great job, but only if I logged out (Wayland) and logged back in using x11. Running under Wayland produces a black video file.

How can I create a screencast file with lossless compression or no compression?

***Edit 1:***
I made some progress with these commands:

```
sudo setcap cap_sys_admin+ep /usr/bin/ffmpeg
ffmpeg -f kmsgrab -r 24 -i :0.0 -s 1920x1080 -vf 'hwdownload,format=bgr0' -t 00:00:10 output.flv
```

The command works, but the output file seems like the video is kind of scrambled.  I have dual monitors(1920x1080) and onboard Intel graphics.  The problem happens on my single monitor system as well.

Comment: Maybe the same way you can enable screen sharing could serve as a starting point? [This article describes it.](http://jgrulich.cz/2018/07/04/how-to-enable-and-use-screen-sharing-on-wayland/)

Comment: John, have you consider why recorders use compression? FullHD=2MB, 24 bit=3 bytes, 25 FPS give 150 MB/s

Comment: Yes Romeo - when editing video, it is best to start with a raw file and compress it at the end after it is edited.  You lose quality if you compress it twice.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but that article is way over my head.  Plus its 3 years old.  PipeWire is the default in Fedora now.